# Get rich text box from server

Tags: c#, ms-word, richtextbox, office-addins

I have a Word 2010 add-in that pulls certain information from the server and displays it in Word within a bookmark. One is the "Rich Text Content Control" found in the Developer tab. Is there a way to "get" it programmatically so I can manipulate it? I am using this method to do something similar for getting a table that is also put in Word by the server:

```
private Table GetTableByBookmarkName(Bookmark bookmark, int i)
{
    Table tbl = bookmark.Range.Tables[i];

    if (tbl != null)
    {
        return tbl;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't provide enough information. As I mentioned in my reply to your related question posted in "Word for Developers" on MSDN, Word doesn't have anything called a "Rich Text box". What, exactly, is this thing you call "Rich text box"?

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I undertand your question is that you want to get a reference to a RichText content control, directly (as opposed to using a bookmark). Yes, this is possible.

1. Use an Index value (1-based!) for the Collection (order in the document): Document.ContentControls[index]
2. Use the Document.SelectContentControlsByTag method to return a collection of content controls having the same value in the Tag property
3. Use the Document.SelectContentControlsByTitle method to return a collection of content controls having the same value in the Title property.

Similarly to bookmarks, a Title and/or a Tag can be assigned to a content control when the document/template is being designed. There's a "Properties" button in the Developer tab, in the same group as the content controls.

Unlike bookmarks, more than one content control can have the same Title / Tag, which is why a collection is returned.